# Append CSS Class

Tags: javascript, css, class

I have a tab-styled navigation menu. My goal:

1. Once the user mousovers tab X. add the "tabActive" class to tab X, if the tab already has the "tabActive" class, then remove it
2. Show Div "X"

I have the second part down, and my java code detects which tab is being hovered, but I can not get my additional class toggled correctly.

My code so far:

**HTML**

```
<div id="subnav">
<div id="nav1" onmouseover="toggleDisplay('contentPayment')"  class="Payment myNav">
<a href="#">Payment</a></div>
<div id="nav2"  onmouseover="toggleDisplay('content-shipping')" class="Shipping myNav">
<a href="#">Shipping</a></div>
<div id="nav3" class="Warranty myNav">
<a href="#">Warranty</a></div>
<div id="nav4" class="Feedback myNav">
<a href="#">Feedback</a></div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>

var divs = new Array();
divs.push("contentPayment");
divs.push("content-shipping");

function hasClass(element, cls) {
    return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}

function toggleDisplay(id) {
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    var item = document.getElementById(divs[i]);
    item.style.display = 'none';
}

//Now use the passed ID to show the div you wanted to show
var target = document.getElementById(id);
target.style.display = 'block';

if (id == "contentPayment") {
    var CurrentTab = document.getElementById("nav1");
    var AlreadyActive = hasClass("nav1", " tabActive");

    if (AlreadyActive == true) {
        CurrentTab.className = "Payment myNav";
    } else {

        CurrentTab.className += " " + "tabActive";
    }

}
}

</script>​
```

Any ideas what my problem is? I know jQuery would be *much* easier, but I am coding for eBay and they do not allow it. How do I get my tabActive class to toggle correctly?

Comment: You should be passing in `CurrentTab` not `"nav1"` to `hasClass`

Comment: Still a no-go..Thanks though.

Comment: why does ebay not allow jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in the `toggleDisplay` function. I think you wanted to do this:

```
var divs = new Array();
divs.push("contentPayment");
divs.push("content-shipping");

function toggleDisplay(id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        var item = document.getElementById(divs[i]);
        item.style.display = divs[i] == id ? 'block' : 'none';
        item.className = item.className.replace(' tabActive', '');
    }

    var target = document.getElementById(id);
    target.className += " " + "tabActive";
}

function showAllTabs() {
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        var item = document.getElementById(divs[i]);
        item.style.display = 'block';
        item.className = item.className.replace(' tabActive', '');
    }
}​
```

You need to show all the tabs when mouse is moved out of that tab, otherwise you would never been able to mouse over the hidden ones.

```
<div id="subnav">
<div id="contentPayment" onmouseover="toggleDisplay('contentPayment')" onmouseout="showAllTabs()" class="Payment myNav">
<a href="#">Payment</a></div>
<div id="content-shipping"  onmouseover="toggleDisplay('content-shipping')" onmouseout="showAllTabs()" class="Shipping myNav">
<a href="#">Shipping</a></div>
<div id="nav3" class="Warranty myNav">
<a href="#">Warranty</a></div>
<div id="nav4" class="Feedback myNav">
<a href="#">Feedback</a></div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some poj add, remove, and has class functions a while back. They looked like this:

```
    hasClass: function( element, className ) {
        return ( element.className.search( new RegExp( '(^|\s)' + className + '($|\s)' ) ) !== -1 );
    },
    addClass: function( element, className ) {
        if ( element.className === '' ) {
            element.className = className;
        } else {
            // add class only if element does not already have the class
            if ( this.hasClass( element, className ) === false ) element.className += ' ' + className;
        }
    },
    removeClass: function( element, className ) {
        element.className = element.className.replace( new RegExp( '(^|\s)' + className + '($|\s)' ), ' ' ).replace( /^\s|\s$/, '' );
    },
```